# Errors while restoring sources.list

Tags: apt, repository, software-sources

Unfortunately I changed my Ubuntu 18.04 sources.list. How can I restore sources.list file in my Ubuntu software?

I got these errors while editing sources.list:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

** (gedit:3491): WARNING **: 10:51:37.148: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:3491): WARNING **: 10:51:37.148: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:3491): WARNING **: 10:51:52.500: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

$ sudo apt-get upadate
E: Invalid operation upadate
```

Comment: These aren't errors but some warnings whoch you can definitely ignore. Second, don't use GUI with sudo rather consider using pico/nano/vim. Third, Try to update that from Software and Updates app, choose components and server (if needed). Fourth, you misspelled `update`.